# Why isn't this preg_match pattern working? (detect 4 or 5 digit strings)

Tags: php

This gives an error saying the delimiters are wrong but i don't understand why:

```
preg_match( $search_location, "/(\d{4,5})/", $matches);
```

Comment: Seriously!  Did you look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php?

Comment: `preg_match( "/(\d{4,5})/", $search_location,  $matches);`

Answer (score 1):

The manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php says

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

You have

```
preg_match( $search_location, "/(\d{4,5})/", $matches);
```

Your arguments are out of order.